# Are all highly composite numbers even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

A highly composite number is a positive integer with more divisors than any smaller positive integer. Are all highly composite numbers even (excluding 1 of course)? I can't find anything about this question online, so I can only assume that they obviously are. But I cannot see why.

Comment: [The exponents of the prime factors are nonincreasing and the last one is $1$.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. Given an odd number $n$, choose any prime factor $p$, and let $k\geq 1$ be the number such that $p^k\mid n$ but $p^{k+1}\not\mid n$. Then $n\times\frac{2^k}{p^k}$ has the same number of factors, and is smaller.

Comment: The same idea extends to show the primes dividing a highly composite number must be the smallest primes and the exponents must decrease as the primes get larger.

Comment: The associated OEIS sequence is [A025487](http://oeis.org/A025487).

Comment: Furthermore, from 6 on, they are all multiples of 3.  From 12 on, they are all multiples of 4.  From 60 on, they are all multiples of 5.  I believe that for any given factor N, there is a point after which all numbers in the sequence are multiples of N.  I don't have a proof for this, but it seems like it's probably the case.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I would love to have proofs of these.

Comment: @Charles: isn't the relevant sequence A002182 (http://oeis.org/A002182)?

Comment: @MichaelLugo Those are the highly composite numbers themselves. The sequence I posted is relevant to the proof idea Ross posted.

Comment: @Charles I see.

Comment: @MichaelLugo But thanks for linking those, +1 for visibility. :)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yes, even if N is not small and is [prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205379).